# Azure Bicep in DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

I have an existing Azure DevOps release pipeline that deploys resources using Azure CLI to multiple environments DEV, TEST, PROD.

[image]

I'd like to switch gradually to using Bicep files.

Microsoft's [Quickstart: Integrate Bicep with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/add-template-to-azure-pipelines?tabs=CLI) shows how to build a **build** pipeline using an inline CLI scipt, but I wasn't able to find help on how to setup a bicep task in a **release** pipeline.

There are no official bicep tasks for release pipelines like there are for ARM files.

Do I need to use a Azure CLI script task type to run something like
`az deployment group create --resource-group $(resourceGroupName) --template-file $(templateFile) --parameters "{ \"someparameter1\": { \"value\": \"$(someparameter1)\" } }"`?

Comment: for the moment, you need to use the `Az CLI` task.

Comment: That quickstart is actually showing you a release pipeline; it's not doing any building, just deploying azure resources.

Answer (score 4):

Bicep is a domain-specific language that compiles into ARM-templates, so you have (at least) two possible approaches here:

either you deploy bicep templates with the az deployment group create -command without building them (in which case the az -command compiles Bicep into an ARM-template and deploys that)

OR

you compile the bicep template yourself with bicep build (or az bicep build) and deploy the ARM-template it creates like you have deployed them before.

The first approach is more straightforward, the latter might fit better to your existing approach if you have, for example, existing separate build and release pipelines or utilize some kind of testing for the ARM-templates before deploying them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really good tutorial that provides an answer to your question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/bicep-azure-pipelines/ It's also very well written.

Comment: This tutorial shows how to deploy Bicep using Azure DevOps -> Pipelines -> Pipelines.

The question is about how to deploy Bicep using Azure DevOps -> Pipelines -> Releases.